# Is there an automatic way to size and position a certain object in a series of images?

Tags: photo-editing

For example, I want to achieve something like this youtube video where the face is perfectly sized and positioned every frame

https://youtu.be/65nfbW-27ps

The creator of the video mentions that he had to size and position each of the photos individually, I was wondering if there is a way of automating it?

I’m a newbie to photography and editing so I would be grateful if I could be pointed in the right direction if this has been answered before.

Comment: Hi Aryan and welcome to Photo.SE! It is greatly appreciated if you show your research before asking a question. Have you for example searched for the words ["crop face"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=crop+face) on this website? Did you find anything useful? If not, could you indicate how the search results do not fit your current problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I batch crop based on face location?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/how-can-i-batch-crop-based-on-face-location)

Comment: Hi Saaru, thanks so much for the feedback! What I was looking for was a solution where the program would manipulate the images such that the faces would be exactly aligned if all the photos are layered on top of each other. The thread was about detecting faces and putting them in a general area (in that case, rule or thirds). But that thread did point me in the right direction and gave me some ideas of how I might automate this myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gimp, with the [`ofn-layer-aligner` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/):

- you load both images as layers in the same Gimp image (`File > open` for the first, `File > Open as layers` for the others)
- you set two points on the first (reference) image (typically, the center of the pupils)
- you set two points on the second (target) image (the pupils again)
- the script rotates/scales/moves the target layer so that the points coincide in both images.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically point to the pupils instead of doing it manually?

Comment: Automatic, possibly, accurate enough, remains to be proven. Automatic software may lock on reflections of light in the iris and so somewhat misaligh images. The method above is fairly quick, I used to align images for a timelapse.

Comment: fairly quick? For 3000 photos, this sounds like cruel and inhuman punishment.

Comment: @osullic, artists frequently do far more tedious things for their art... if we assume 20 seconds per image (probably an over estimate) this could be accomplished in less than 17 hours. I've spent that long retouching a single image for a magazine cover.